# Can I use glTranslate and glRotate when my GLSL Version over (#version 120)?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I was using "GLSL Version #120". But now i am trying to do one tutorial and it is using "gl_ClipDistance[0]" inside of vertex shader. And "GLSL Version #120" doesn't support "gl_ClipDistance[0]". Now i need to change GLSL Version with over #120 for example #330 . I also have to change "gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix" inside vertex shader. But my question is i need to change glTranslate,glRotate,glLoadIdentity etc ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use them, but OpenGL will not automatically transfer the resulting matrix to your GLSL, and the older built-in uniform will not be available.

What this means is you'll need to use a glGet to retrieve the matrix to your program code, followed by a glUniform to send it to your shader.

Comment: Thank you too much for your answer. I decided to use "GLM" library. I will setup Projection , View and Model matrix. And i will send them gpu with glUniform4fv right? But i did not understand this : how can i change position my meshes (objects). I could change glTranslatef(); inside glPushMatrix(); when i use "GLSL Version #120". And my second question is what is better calculate ( Projection * 
View * Model) inside display() function and after send one matrix to gpu. Or send all and calculate inside gpu with "GLSL".

Comment: @EmreKaya - these would be better as separate questions; the StackExchange format isn't intended for back-and-forth discussions like a forum; instead it's for separate questions with one topic per question.